# Can I receive emails from [no character]@mydomain.com?

Tags: email

I tried to look for it, but the keywords for this question are just too generic.

If one buy a domain, `mydomain.example`, for example. Is it technically possible to receive emails sent to `@mydomain.example`? **(with nothing before the "`@`")**

Comment: I would suggest that this is a very bad idea and worth avoiding. Even if it was technically possible (as implied by @sportzpikachu), you'll likely encounter a lot of issues with systems that believe it is _**not**_ possible.

Comment: Note, if you want to use your private domain name for mailing, you do it better if you configure your mail server on a way, that it sends all @mydomain.example mails into your IMAP mailbox. So you will be able to use the target usernames to separate between topics.

Answer (score 4):

According to RFC5321, yes, technically this is possible. As shown [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#page-42), a `Mailbox` is made of `Local path@Domain` and `Local path` does not explicitly state that a `quoted string` may not be empty, but this will fall down to your mail software and if it supports it.

Comment: The syntax rules make clear that a localpart cannot be an empty string, at minimum it would be `""`, which is not empty.